# How to get the aspect ratio of an image programmatically

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I get the aspect ratio of an image and store it in a pgf macro for further calculations? For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{image.jpg}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmatsetmacro{\aspectratio}{???} % This variable should contain the aspect ratio of image.jpg
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the image in a box, then the aspect ratio is the (total) height vs width of that box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an `\aspectratio` macro that either prints the aspect ratio or stores it in a macro given as optional argument. The *-form will do a global assignment, in case you need it. The macro (in the example it is `\test`) can be used in `\pgfmathsetmacro` or other environment accepting floating point numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % also loads expl3
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\aspectratio}{smo}
 {% #2 is the image file
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\includegraphics{#2}}
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {
    \__student_aspectratio:nn { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }
   }
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{ \tl_gset:Nx } { \tl_set:Nx } #3
     {
      \__student_aspectratio:nn { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__student_aspectratio:nn
 {
  \fp_eval:n {round( #1 / #2 , 5)}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\aspectratio{example-image}

\aspectratio{example-image-1x1}

\begingroup
\aspectratio*{example-image-9x16}[\test]
\endgroup

\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In `pdftex` you can use the register `\pdfximagebbox` to retrieve the coordinates of the bounding box.  These are

[image]

The width and height of the image are obviously given by

```
width  = [upper-right x] - [lower-left x]
height = [upper-right y] - [lower-left y]
```

and the aspect ratio is simply `width/height`.  Using the `xfp` package to evaluate the floating point expression, the following document prints `1.333...` underneath the image (which has an aspect ratio of 4:3, so it's correct).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xfp}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\fpeval{
  (\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 3 - \pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 1)
  /
  (\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 4 - \pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 2)
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the following error: \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Invalid operation (0)/(0)

Comment: @student It only works in `pdftex` (just guessing).

Comment: I used pdflatex

Answer (score 7):

Here's a trick using `\newcount` registers to store length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fp}
\newcount\boxheight
\newcount\boxwidth
\newcommand\testaspect[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \boxheight=\ht0\relax%
  \boxwidth=\wd0\relax%
  \FPdiv\theaspect{\the\boxheight}{\the\boxwidth}%
  \copy0%
}
\begin{document}
\testaspect{\includegraphics{example-image}}

The aspect ratio is \theaspect.

\testaspect{A}

The aspect ratio is \theaspect.

\testaspect{\tiny A}

The aspect ratio is \theaspect.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I for my actual problem the image is inside of a `\node[inner sep = 0pt] at (0,0) {\testaspect{\includegraphics{image}}}` construction and I need the aspectratio outside of this (in but in the same tikzpicture environment). In this case your solution doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @student In my `\testaspect` macro, after the `\FPdiv` invocation, you should be able to `\global\let\theaspect\theaspect` to make `\theaspect` a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

If node dimensions are needed, `tcolorbox` macros `\tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode` and `\tcbsetmacrotoheighthofnode` can get it and the result be used in other nodes on same tikzpicture. These macros are explained in section [Extracting node dimensions](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=253) (page 263 in v4.10 and page 253 in v4.02).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (A) {\includegraphics[width=145pt]{example-image}};
\tcbsetmacrotowidthofnode\mywidth{A}
\tcbsetmacrotoheightofnode\myheight{A}
\node[below = 3mm of A] (width) {The width of this figure is \the\numexpr\mywidth};
\node[below = 5mm of width] (height) {The height of this figure is \myheight};
\node[below = 5mm of height] (aspect) {The aspectratio of this figure is \pgfmathparse{\mywidth/\myheight}\pgfmathresult};

\node[draw, minimum width=\mywidth, minimum height=\myheight, right=1mm of A]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Macro `\SetToRatio` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383700/4686

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox\mybox

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383700/4686
\makeatletter
\newcommand\SetToRatio[3]{% sets #1 to be the ratio #2/#3, where #2 and #3 
    % are lengths (registers or expressions).
    % The ratio #2/#3 should evaluate to less than 16384 in absolute value to 
    % avoid arithmetic overflow. It will be computed as fixed point
    % number with about 4 or 5 digits after decimal mark.
    \edef #1%
        {\strip@pt\dimexpr
         \numexpr\dimexpr#2\relax*65536/\dimexpr#3\relax\relax sp\relax}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\sbox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[draft]{example-image.pdf}}    
% you may prefix this with \global if executed within scope limiting location
\SetToRatio\aspectratio{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox\relax}{\wd\mybox}

% debugging
% \show\aspectratio

% now use it !
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\pgfmatsetmacro{\aspectratio}{???} % This variable should contain the aspect ratio of image.jpg
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```