# How can I calculate a number of lines needed to fit the text?

Tags: tex-core, grid-typesetting

I want to make a command that works like

```
\CalcNumber{<the text>}{<width>}{<cs>}
```

And stores the number of lines (i. e. height in `\baselineskip` rounded up) needed for `<the text>` in `<cs>` if it was typeset in a box of a width `<width>`.

For example `\CalcNumber{A}{\columwith}{\AHeight}\AHeight` should yield `1`, while something like `\CalcNumber{M M M}{1em}{\MMMHeight}\MMMHeight` should give smth like `3`.

How can I do that?

P. S. A LuaLaTeX solution is also welcomed.

Comment: Have a look at [get height on a block of latex output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2939450/7440933).

Comment: `\newbox\calcbox \setbox\calcbox\vbox{\hsize#2\relax#1\par} \edef#3{\the\dimexpr(\dp\calcbox+\ht\calcbox)/(\baselineskip)\relax}` Sorry, haven't tested and probably doesn't work, because of limitations of `\dimexpr` and may be because of problems with the syntax (I don't know much about boxes), but something like that would work.

Comment: [Count Lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317713/count-lines-in-a-block-of-text)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242003/21930

Comment: @dexteritas the solution assumes that the text fits one line.

Comment: @Manuel no, it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you need this macro to be expandable? Or is it enough if it works when “executed”? (Because something like @Manuel's first solution looks like it should work at least in the latter case.) Also, this may be easier with LuaTeX, so if that's acceptable to you there may be more solutions.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR not sure, I need to calculate the height to put it inside a minipage of that height. Lua is possible, since I use LuaLaTeX

Comment: can it be assumed that there is no display math, or math with height+depth greater than `\baselineskip` in the text to be measured?

Comment: @barbarabeeton no, I would like to calculate it for display math also.

Comment: IMO the question is not well-defined. If you can have large display math in it, what does it even mean to talk of the number of lines? Does all the math count as “one line”? And do you want the number of lines, or the height? And if *your* actual use-case is *“I need to calculate the height to put it inside a minipage of that height”* why not ask that as the question (because there are other solutions to that, that do not involve this complicated workaround of calculating the height or the number of lines)?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR as I have said, I need to calculate the height, measured in `\baselineskip`. The idea is to use tikz to overlay something over the text in order to preserve grid system.

Comment: You should really better describe what you are trying to achieve. To overlay text I would e.g. probably save the positions at the begin and end of the text and use this in the next compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox` to box the content in a `minipage` of the given width and store its total height, then calculate the factor of the baselineskip using eTeX (and finally `discard` the content).

This is similar to other answers which using boxing, but a more out-of-the-box solution (no pun intended).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength\mycalclength

\newcommand\CalcNumber[3]{%
    \adjustbox{minipage={#2}, gstore totalheight=\mycalclength, discard}{#1}%
    \edef#3{\the\numexpr\dimexpr \mycalclength/\baselineskip\relax\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

\CalcNumber{A}{\columnwidth}{\AHeight}\AHeight

\CalcNumber{M M M M M M M}{1em}{\MMMHeight}\MMMHeight

\end{document}
```

If you rearrange the order of the arguments and have the content last, you can use the feature of `\adjustbox` to read the last argument as box, not as argument, allowing for verbatim and other special content. Note that the assignment is then global as it happens in a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength\mycalclength

\newcommand\CalcNumber[2]{%
    \adjustbox{minipage={#1}, gstore totalheight=\mycalclength, execute={\gdef#2{\the\numexpr\dimexpr \mycalclength/\baselineskip\relax\relax}}, discard}
}

\begin{document}

\CalcNumber{\columnwidth}{\AHeight}{A}\AHeight

\CalcNumber{1em}{\MMMHeight}{M M M M M M M}\MMMHeight

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways that you can do this: one is with `\prevgraf`, and the other by calculating the lines manually.

If you do it with `\prevgraf`, that gives you the amount of lines in the previous paragraph. This will only work if your input is meant to be only one paragraph. What we do is we use `\setbox0` to put the text into a vbox which we don't print. In the vbox, we set the `hsize` to your width, the second argument, and then print the first argument as a paragraph. We manually end the paragraph with `\par`, and the use `\xdef` to save the current value of `\prevgraf` into the cs you passed as the third argument.

```
\def\CalcNumber#1#2#3{%
  \setbox0\vbox{\hsize=#2 \noindent#1\par\xdef#3{\the\prevgraf}}}
```

If your input is more than one paragraph, then you can use the same setup as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\CalcNumber#1#2#3{%
  \setbox0\vbox{\hsize=#2 \noindent#1}}
\@tempcnta=\dimexpr(\ht0+\dp0)/\baselineskip
\xdef#3{\the\@tempcnta}}
\makeatother
```

In a similar fashion to our other approach, we typeset our text in a box. We need to define our `\CalcNumber` as `\long`, so it can accept text of more than one paragraph. Then, we add the height and depth of the box, and divide by `\baselineskip`, saving it in a LaTeX temporary count register (this will round the number for us). We then store this in our give control sequence, as above.

A caveat here is that   this will use whatever the baselineskip is when you call the macro. You'd need to account for variations in font sizes, depending on what you plan on using this for.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, ConTeXt provides a macro `\determinenofline{...}` that determines the number of lines of the content (when typeset in a `\vbox`). The result is stored in the counter: `\noflines`.

This counts the number of typeset lines (not the height in the multiple of `\lineheight` (or what is called `\baselineskip` in LaTeX). Here is one example from `supp-box.mkiv` to show that:

```
\starttext

\determinenoflines{test\\test}
\the\noflines

\determinenoflines{\bfd test\\test}
\the\noflines

\determinenoflines{\definedfont[Sans at 40pt]test\\test}
\the\noflines
\stoptext
```

All three of these tests give `2`.

To count the number of lines for a content of a specific width, you can simply set `\hsize` for the content. For example:

```
\starttext
\vbox{\hsize=3cm \input ward\relax}

\determinenoflines{\hsize=3cm \input ward\relax}
\the\noflines
\stoptext
```

which gives (the first `\vbox` is just to verify the result).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt based on the `lineno` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[running]{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{mylines}
\newsavebox{\marmot}
\newcommand{\CalcNumber}[3]{
\savebox{\marmot}{\begin{minipage}{#2}\linenumbers*
\begin{internallinenumbers}
#1 \par
\setcounter{mylines}{\thelinenumber}\addtocounter{mylines}{-1}
\end{internallinenumbers}
\end{minipage}}
\let#3=\themylines}
\begin{document}

\CalcNumber{\lipsum[1]}{8cm}{\myx}

\myx

\CalcNumber{A}{8cm}{\myy}

\myy


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses `\vsplit` to count the lines.  The only surprise was from `intemise` which adds a blank line (and some negative `\vspace`) at the start.

One can return the number of lines by adding `\theNLcount` to the end of the macro.  In this case, I wanted to show the number using `\marginpar` and it was using `\marginparwidth` as the default width.

Since you want to split off only one line at a time, it is better so request as little as possible, hence the 0pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{NLcount}

\newcommand{\numberoflines}[2][\linewidth]% #1=width (optional), #2=text
{\bgroup
  \hsize=#1\relax
  \clubpenalty=0
  \widowpenalty=0
  \displaywidowpenalty=0
  \predisplaypenalty=0
  \postdisplaypenalty=0
  \interlinepenalty=0
  \setbox0=\vbox{#2}%
  \setcounter{NLcount}{0}%
  \loop\ifdim\ht0>0pt
    \stepcounter{NLcount}%
    \setbox1=\vsplit0 to 0pt
  \repeat
\egroup}% \theNLcount

\begin{document}

\numberoflines{above \[x=a\] more text \begin{equation} y=b \end{equation} below}

\hrule\leavevmode\marginpar{\theNLcount{} lines}
above \[x=a\] more text \begin{equation} y=b \end{equation} below
\hrule

\numberoflines{above\newline \rule{1in}{1in}\newline below}

\hrule\leavevmode\marginpar{\theNLcount{} lines}
above\newline \rule{1in}{1in}\newline below
\hrule

\numberoflines{\begin{itemize}
  \item One
  \item Two
\end{itemize}}

\hrule\leavevmode\marginpar{\theNLcount{} lines}
\begin{itemize}
  \item One
  \item Two
\end{itemize}
\hrule

\numberoflines{\blindtext}

\hrule\leavevmode\marginpar{\theNLcount{} lines}
\blindtext
\hrule

\numberoflines{\tiny\blindtext}

\hrule\leavevmode\marginpar{\theNLcount{} lines}
{\tiny\blindtext}
\hrule

\newpage
\numberoflines[2in]{\blindtext}
\hrule\noindent\marginpar{\theNLcount{} lines}
\parbox{2in}{\strut\blindtext}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A LaTeX solution, maybe a bit more complicated than necessary, but it is working:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter

\def\RoundLines#1\relax{%
  \@tempdimb=#1\relax
  \@tempcnta=0
  \loop%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0\p@%
    \global\@tempdimb\dimexpr\@tempdimb-\baselineskip\relax
    \global\advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \repeat
  \xdef\result{\@tempcnta}%
  }

\newbox\calcbox
\def\CalcNumber#1#2#3{%
  \edef\@argii{#2}%
  \expandafter\@tempdima\@argii\relax
  \setbox\calcbox\vbox{\hsize\@tempdima\relax\noindent#1\par}%
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr(\dp\calcbox+\ht\calcbox)\relax
  \RoundLines\@tempdima\relax
  \expandafter\xdef\csname#3\endcsname{\the\result}%
  % \copy\calcbox%% for testing
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\CalcNumber{A}{20mm}{AHeight}
has {\AHeight} lines

\CalcNumber{M M M}{1mm}{MMMHeight}
has {\MMMHeight} lines
\end{document}
```