# Store result of \ratio calculation for repeated use

Tags: beamer, pdftex, scaling, lengths, calc

I am using pdflatex with the beamer package to create a presentation template that is similar to the PowerPoint template provided by my company.

I want the company logo to have the same size in my template as in the original one. I know the width of the logo in the PowerPoint template, the page width of the PowerPoint slides and the width of the slides in beamer.

At this moment, I manage to achieve this scaling as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{calc}

\newlength{\pptwidth}
\setlength{\pptwidth}{254mm} % width of PPT slide
\newlength{\beamerwidth}
\setlength{\beamerwidth}{160mm} % width of beamer slide
\newlength{\logowidth}
\setlength{\logowidth}{110mm} % width of logo in PPT slide

\includegraphics[width=\logowidth*\ratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}]{logo.png}
```

This works just fine. Nevertheless, I will also need to scale many other figures and lengths in the same manner. For this purpose, I would like to be able to store the result of `\ratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}`, such that I can write something like

```
\newcommand{\widthscale}{\ratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}}
\includegraphics[width=\logowidth*\widthscale]{logo.png}
```

However, this does not seem to work. I also tried solutions with `\def`, `\edef`, `\expandafter` that I found elsewhere, but they all seem to fail.

Is it possible to save such a `\ratio` in a variable, such that it can be used later on?

Comment: Macro `\SetToRatio` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383700/4686 ?

Comment: @jfbu For the specific case that I am asking about, that might indeed also work. However, I plan to use this same method for other scalings, where the arguments of `\ratio` might have different dimensions (eg. pt and mm). For those situations I think the `\ratio` command from the `calc` package is very useful.

Comment: As long as the arguments you use, whether with `pt`, `mm`,  or `in` are genuine dimension expressions (or dimen registers or LaTeX length variables), `\SetToRatio` will work.

Comment: `calc` package was for an era pre-dating wide use of `e-TeX` extension. It is sort of obsoleted by `\dimexpr` and friends. Although of course you can enjoy its `\widthof`, but this is but one line of TeX code or two.

Comment: The main reason `calc` package is used is that the reference books (Lamport's, the Companion) describe an old era, which is obsoleted since 2004 for TeXLive. And of course many packages use it, so its there even without the LaTeX user asking for it, often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\ratio` command in `calc` does not compute the quotient directly, it is an intermediate construction for use in other calculations.  What you need to is to include this in a complete calculation so the result becomes a real.  The simplest way to do this, is to multiply by `1`:

```
 \edef\widthscale{1*\ratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\pptwidth}
\setlength{\pptwidth}{254mm} % width of PPT slide
\newlength{\beamerwidth}
\setlength{\beamerwidth}{160mm} % width of beamer slide
\newlength{\logowidth}
\setlength{\logowidth}{110mm} % width of logo in PPT slide

\newcommand{\widthscale}{1*\ratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\logowidth*\ratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}]{example-image-a.png}

\includegraphics[width=\logowidth*\widthscale]{example-image-a.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for the suggestion! Using `\newcommand` instead of `\edef` makes sure that things do not get defined multiple times I guess?

Comment: @AndrewSwann you have updated the MWE but not the first paragraph :) (_deleting my comments_)

Answer (score 5):

I would use expl3 instead of calc:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\dimratio { m m }
{
 \fp_eval:n
  {
   \dim_to_fp:n { #1 } /  \dim_to_fp:n { #2 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\pptwidth}
\setlength{\pptwidth}{254mm} % width of PPT slide
\newlength{\beamerwidth}
\setlength{\beamerwidth}{160mm} % width of beamer slide
\newlength{\logowidth}
\setlength{\logowidth}{110mm} % width of logo in PPT slide

\newcommand\myscale{\dimratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\myscale\logowidth]{example-image.png}

\end{document}
```

You can also store the computed value with

```
 \edef\myscale{\dimratio{\beamerwidth}{\pptwidth}}
```