# ssconvert convert to table, ratio calculate error : Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tables, calc, convert

ssconvert convert to table,but ratio calculate error.

I searched around and found no solution. Is there a problem with ssconvert's table conversion?

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\inputGnumericTable{} 
\usepackage{inputenc}  
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{longtable}      
\usepackage{calc}         
\usepackage{multirow}      
\usepackage{hhline}       
 \usepackage{ifthen}      

\usepackage{lscape}  


\begin{document}



test

\input{te.tex} 


\end{document}
```

`te.tex` content

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  This is the header of a LaTeX2e file exported from Gnumeric.    %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  This file can be compiled as it stands or included in another   %%
%%  LaTeX document. The table is based on the longtable package so  %%
%%  the longtable options (headers, footers...) can be set in the   %%
%%  preamble section below (see PRAMBLE).                           %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  To include the file in another, the following two lines must be %%
%%  in the including file:                                          %%
%%        \def\inputGnumericTable{}                                 %%
%%  at the beginning of the file and:                               %%
%%        \input{name-of-this-file.tex}                             %%
%%  where the table is to be placed. Note also that the including   %%
%%  file must use the following packages for the table to be        %%
%%  rendered correctly:                                             %%
%%    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                                 %%
%%    \usepackage{color}                                            %%
%%    \usepackage{array}                                            %%
%%    \usepackage{longtable}                                        %%
%%    \usepackage{calc}                                             %%
%%    \usepackage{multirow}                                         %%
%%    \usepackage{hhline}                                           %%
%%    \usepackage{ifthen}                                           %%
%%  optionally (for landscape tables embedded in another document): %%
%%    \usepackage{lscape}                                           %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%  This section checks if we are begin input into another file or  %%
%%  the file will be compiled alone. First use a macro taken from   %%
%%  the TeXbook ex 7.7 (suggestion of Han-Wen Nienhuys).            %%
\def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax}


%%  Check for the \def token for inputed files. If it is not        %%
%%  defined, the file will be processed as a standalone and the     %%
%%  preamble will be used.                                          %%
\ifundefined{inputGnumericTable}

%%  We must be able to close or not the document at the end.        %%
    \def\gnumericTableEnd{\end{document}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  This is the PREAMBLE. Change these values to get the right      %%
%%  paper size and other niceties.                                  %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \documentclass[12pt%
              %,landscape%
                    ]{report}
       \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
       \usepackage{fullpage}
       \usepackage{color}
       \usepackage{array}
       \usepackage{longtable}
       \usepackage{calc}
       \usepackage{multirow}
       \usepackage{hhline}
       \usepackage{ifthen}

    \begin{document}


%%  End of the preamble for the standalone. The next section is for %%
%%  documents which are included into other LaTeX2e files.          %%
\else

%%  We are not a stand alone document. For a regular table, we will %%
%%  have no preamble and only define the closing to mean nothing.   %%
    \def\gnumericTableEnd{}

%%  If we want landscape mode in an embedded document, comment out  %%
%%  the line above and uncomment the two below. The table will      %%
%%  begin on a new page and run in landscape mode.                  %%
%       \def\gnumericTableEnd{\end{landscape}}
%       \begin{landscape}


%%  End of the else clause for this file being \input.              %%
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%%  The rest is the gnumeric table, except for the closing          %%
%%  statement. Changes below will alter the table's appearance.     %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\providecommand{\gnumericmathit}[1]{#1} 
%%  Uncomment the next line if you would like your numbers to be in %%
%%  italics if they are italizised in the gnumeric table.           %%
%\renewcommand{\gnumericmathit}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\providecommand{\gnumericPB}[1]%
{\let\gnumericTemp=\\#1\let\\=\gnumericTemp\hspace{0pt}}
 \ifundefined{gnumericTableWidthDefined}
        \newlength{\gnumericTableWidth}
        \newlength{\gnumericTableWidthComplete}
        \newlength{\gnumericMultiRowLength}
        \global\def\gnumericTableWidthDefined{}
 \fi
%% The following setting protects this code from babel shorthands.  %%
 \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\languageshorthands}}{}{\languageshorthands{english}}
%%  The default table format retains the relative column widths of  %%
%%  gnumeric. They can easily be changed to c, r or l. In that case %%
%%  you may want to comment out the next line and uncomment the one %%
%%  thereafter                                                      %%
\providecommand\gnumbox{\makebox[0pt]}
%%\providecommand\gnumbox[1][]{\makebox}

%% to adjust positions in multirow situations                       %%
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{\jot}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{\doublerulesep}

%%  The \setlongtables command keeps column widths the same across  %%
%%  pages. Simply comment out next line for varying column widths.  %%
\setlongtables

\setlength\gnumericTableWidth{%
    218pt+%
    218pt+%
    218pt+%
0pt}
\def\gumericNumCols{3}
\setlength\gnumericTableWidthComplete{\gnumericTableWidth+%
         \tabcolsep*\gumericNumCols*2+\arrayrulewidth*\gumericNumCols}
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\gnumericTableWidthComplete > \linewidth}}%
         {\def\gnumericScale{\ratio{\linewidth-%
                        \tabcolsep*\gumericNumCols*2-%
                        \arrayrulewidth*\gumericNumCols}%
{\gnumericTableWidth}}}%
{\def\gnumericScale{1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                  %%
%% The following are the widths of the various columns. We are      %%
%% defining them here because then they are easier to change.       %%
%% Depending on the cell formats we may use them more than once.    %%
%%                                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColA}}{\newlength{\gnumericColA}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColA}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{218pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColB}}{\newlength{\gnumericColB}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColB}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{218pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\gnumericColC}}{\newlength{\gnumericColC}}{}\settowidth{\gnumericColC}{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{218pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}

\begin{longtable}[c]{%
    b{\gnumericColA}%
    b{\gnumericColB}%
    b{\gnumericColC}%
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  The longtable options. (Caption, headers... see Goosens, p.124) %%
%   \caption{The Table Caption.}             \\ %
% \hline    % Across the top of the table.
%%  The rest of these options are table rows which are placed on    %%
%%  the first, last or every page. Use \multicolumn if you want.    %%

%%  Header for the first page.                                      %%
%   \multicolumn{3}{c}{The First Header} \\ \hline 
%   \multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag}  %Column 1
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 2
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} \\ \hline %Last column
%   \endfirsthead

%%  The running header definition.                                  %%
%   \hline
%   \multicolumn{3}{l}{\ldots\small\slshape continued} \\ \hline
%   \multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag}  %Column 1
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} %Column 2
%   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{colTag} \\ \hline %Last column
%   \endhead

%%  The running footer definition.                                  %%
%   \hline
%   \multicolumn{3}{r}{\small\slshape continued\ldots} \\
%   \endfoot

%%  The ending footer definition.                                   %%
%   \multicolumn{3}{c}{That's all folks} \\ \hline 
%   \endlastfoot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\hhline{|-|-|-}
     \multicolumn{1}{|p{\gnumericColA}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{1}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{p{\gnumericColB}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{2}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{p{\gnumericColC}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{3}}
\\
\hhline{|---|}
     \multicolumn{1}{|p{\gnumericColA}|}%
    {\setlength{\gnumericMultiRowLength}{0pt}%
     \addtolength{\gnumericMultiRowLength}{\gnumericColA}%
     \multirow{3}[1]{\gnumericMultiRowLength}{\parbox{\gnumericMultiRowLength}{%
     \gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{4}}}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{p{\gnumericColB}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{6}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{p{\gnumericColC}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{7}}
\\
\hhline{~|-|-|}
     \multicolumn{1}{|p{\gnumericColA}|}%
    {}
    &\multicolumn{2}{p{ \gnumericColB+%
    \gnumericColC+%
    \tabcolsep*2*1}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{5}}
\\
\hhline{~|-|-|}
     \multicolumn{1}{|p{\gnumericColA}|}%
    {}
    &\multicolumn{1}{p{\gnumericColB}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{8}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{p{\gnumericColC}|}%
    {\gnumericPB{\centering}\gnumbox{9}}
\\
\hhline{|-|-|-|}
\end{longtable}

\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\languageshorthands}}{}{\languageshorthands{\languagename}}
\gnumericTableEnd
```

error notes:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. ...{218pt*\gnumericScale}@{}}x\end{tabular}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem has been solved.

I see thise

```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437488/store-result-of-ratio-calculation-for-repeated-use
```

I see